# image is uploaded in cloudinary but the ui is not showing the image whether the image is uploaded or not?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, cloudinary

i have a signup form in jsx i want to take image as an input and upload the image in cloudinary and the url should be stored in the useState hook but image is stored in cloudinary but ui is going blank after that

```
{loading && <p>Uploading image...</p>}
                            {signup.picture && !loading ? (
                                <div>
                                    <p>Uploaded Image Preview:</p>
                                    <Image cloudName="my_cloud_name" publicId={signup.picture} width="100" height="100" crop="fill" />
                                </div>
                            ): null} {!loading && !signup.picture && (
                                <div>
                                  <p>Error loading image. Please try again.</p>
                                </div>
                              )}
```

i am expecting that ui should show that image is uploaded

Comment: Your question makes sense. Adding some previews like screenshots could help get answers sooner than usual.

Comment: sorry its solved now i solved the probelm thanks !